# Relation does not exist but relation already exists messages

Tags: database, postgresql, pgadmin

While I was creating some tables on pgadmin, I created a table of relations. The problem is that when I created it, I got a success message, but when I try to drop or select it I get the messages 'table "full_location" does not exist' and 'relation "full_location" does not exist' for each of the cases. Also when I try to recreate it I get the message 'relation "full_location" already exists'!!! What is going on?

Comment: Can you see your table `full_location` in pgadmin  table  list ?

Comment: See if this will give you error or some result: `select relkind from pg_class where oid = 'full_location'::regclass::oid`

Comment: @OtoShavadze  No I cannot see my table on the pgadmin table list, I refreshed the list, my schema and closed and reopened pgadmin, still it does not show.

Comment: @ŁukaszKamiński I executed it, it gave error 'ERROR:  relation "full_location" does not exist
LINE 1: select relkind from pg_class where oid = 'full_location'::re...'

Comment: How about this one? `select oid::regclass, relkind from pg_class where relname = 'full_location'` It should give you some data, regardless of schema where this relation is in.

Comment: Could this be a path issue? When creating the table, be sure to mention the schema name as well-- do the same when querying.

Comment: Look, the postgresql database is from the university, you can only access it by creating your own database within in it, with your username and password and you can only access your schema, there are no other paths.

Comment: @ŁukaszKamiński yes this one gave data, an empty table with 2 columns "oid" type: regclass and "relkind" type: char.